# how to wrap/scroll text with U8G2

Tags: arduino-uno, u8glib

Does anyone know how to wrap and or text using the U8G2 Libary?   I know there are other libraries that do this for you, but I'd like to use U8G2.

Thank you!

my code's here for reference.  It's not clean, but it works for now https://create.arduino.cc/editor/shaiss/0a2736f4-fb79-4e12-b9d7-fb15ff6757b7/preview

Comment: You have to do it manually. Scrolling is a simple matter of printing substrings and padding with spaces. Wrapping is a simple matter of printing substrings on different lines.

Comment: The Arduino Uno has very limited amount of memory to implement scrolling and wrapping of text for an LCD driver in general. The sketch has to do this, e.g. calculate line breaks, sub-section of text to be displayed, update when focus changes (i.e. scroll), save text, etc. Your sketch seems to be only a limited amount of text so you should be able to do this calculations, save of state, text box projection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
void loop(void) {
    u8g2_uint_t x;

    u8g2.firstPage();
    do {

        // draw the scrolling text at current offset
        x = offset;
        u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_inb30_mr);       // set the target font
        do {                                // repeated drawing of the scrolling text...
            u8g2.drawUTF8(x, 30, text);         // draw the scolling text
            x += width;                     // add the pixel width of the scrolling text
        } while( x < u8g2.getDisplayWidth() );      // draw again until the complete display is filled

        u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_inb16_mr);       // draw the current pixel width
        u8g2.setCursor(0, 58);
        u8g2.print(width);                  // this value must be lesser than 128 unless U8G2_16BIT is set

    } while ( u8g2.nextPage() );

    offset-=1;                          // scroll by one pixel
    if ( (u8g2_uint_t)offset < (u8g2_uint_t)-width )    
        offset = 0;                         // start over again

    delay(10);                          // do some small delay
}
```

this is taken from [here](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/blob/master/sys/arduino/u8g2_page_buffer/ScrollingText/ScrollingText.ino).

It is an excellent lib, but it is can require big amount of memory, fit very well on ESP8266 (tried on nodeMCU) / ESP32.

Of course on ESP32 it is faster.

Used for small OLED 0.98" screen